# v-for inside v-for displaying data in onclick event

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, v-for

hello everyone i have array of objects, and inside each object i have also array of objects..
i did the v-for inside the v-for to display data
at first i wanted for each row to show the data of the first element of the each child of the parent array and onClick event, i wanted to change the data only in the specifique row.

```
infos: [{
    name: 'name1',
    infosName: [{
        place: 'place.1.1',
        surface: '100'
      },
      {
        place: 'place.1.2',
        surface: '200'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    infosName: [{
        place: 'place.2.1',
        surface: '300'
      },
      {
        place: 'place.2.2',
        surface: '400'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i created a method to display the data and got on parametres Two indexs
this a jsfiddle to understand more the problem

Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/f0ehwacm/2

Comment: Please show exactly what result you're expecting, because this description seems a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @RoboRobok thank you for ur answer, what i wanted is when u click on the span (in the fiddljs) its will dispaly the right information, but my code dosn't its show the right nformation but it changed also in ther rows

Comment: Again, please show exactly what results, because - quote - "at first i wanted for each row to show the data of the first element of the each child of the parent array and onClick event, i wanted to change the data only in the specifique row." - doesn't sound very clear.

Comment: please have a look at the jsfidle to know what im talkin about,
in the exemple i wanted when u click on specifique span u show the data of the specefique index of the array

Comment: Okay, I don't think we're understanding each other. Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues needing fixing, but you are on the right lines.

#### Most importantly, you need to store not just one "myIndex" but a separate "myIndex" for each row

That is the root cause of your problem.

#### Let me rephrase your question?

I believe you are hoping for four buttons. The top two buttons choose between two options.

Completely separately, the bottom two buttons choose between two options.

It would be easier for readers to understand your intention if you called the two top buttons "Question 1, Option A", and "Question 1, Option B". And then the bottom two "Question 2...". Then they would understand why when you click on one of the buttons, you want to affect the output of the table for that row only.

[image]

#### Avoid using generic terms like "index" and "i"

These make it unnecessarily difficult for people to understand what you intend. Better to use a concrete noun, in this case "question" or "answer", and prefix it with "i" when you mean the index, such as "iQuestion" for the index of the question and "question" for the question itself.

#### You seem to have a single function "getInfos" which does BOTH getting and setting of information

This is a major problem. You should separate the two functions.

When you click, you want to run a "set" function, that updates your index.

When you are simply displaying, you can access a "get" function, which does *not* change anything.

#### You need to store an index for each row

In my terminology, you need to store the index of your answer to each question.

So instead of this.myIndex starting at 0, you have it starting at [0,0]. Each of the two values can be updated separately, allowing the program to update the answer to one row (i.e. one question), while leaving the other row unchanged.

I have renamed this variable to this.myAnswer to make it easier to understand.

#### this.$set when writing to an array that you want Vue to react to

I initially wrote the "setAnswer" function as follows:

```
this.myAnswer[iQuestion]=iAnswer
```

However, I found that the on-screen display was not updating. This is a common problem in Vue, when you update not the main property listed in `data()`, but an array element of that property.

This is because Vue is not tracking the updates of the array elements, only the array itself. So if you were to reassign the entire array, Vue would notice.

The workaround is to tell Vue explicitly that you are updating something that needs to be reactive. Vue will then update it on screen.

To do this, change your assignment from this format:

```
this.array[index] = value
```

To this

```
this.$set(this.array, index, value)
```

Vue provides this function `this.$set`, which executes your normal `this.array[index] = value` *and* tells Vue to do the screen update.

#### How to cope with missing "infosName"

In response to your question in the comments. You have a convenient place to solve this: your `getAnswer()` function.

Change from this:

```
getAnswer(iQuestion,iAnswer){
    return {
    'name' : this.infos[iQuestion].infosName[iAnswer].place,
    'surface' : this.infos[iQuestion].infosName[iAnswer].surface
  }
```

to this:

```
getAnswer(iQuestion,iAnswer){
    if (this.infos.length>iQuestion &&
        this.infos[iQuestion].infosName &&
        this.infos[iQuestion].infosName.length>iAnswer 
    ){
        return {
            'name' : this.infos[iQuestion].infosName[iAnswer].place,
            'surface' : this.infos[iQuestion].infosName[iAnswer].surface
        }
    else return {
    name : "",
    surface: ""
```

}
}

#### Solution

html:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(question,iQuestion) in infos">
        <div class="row d-flex">
<span style="margin-right:10px" v-for="(answer,iAnswer) in question.infosName" class="badge badge-primary" @click="setAnswer(iQuestion,iAnswer)"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="margin-right:10px;cursor: pointer"></i>{{ answer.place }}</span>        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <p>Name : {{ getAnswer(iQuestion,myAnswer[iQuestion]).name }} </p>
            <p>Surface : {{ getAnswer(iQuestion,myAnswer[iQuestion]).surface }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el :'#app',
  data : function(){
    return {
        myAnswer : [0,0],
    infos : [
            {
            name : 'name1',
          infosName : [
                {
                place : 'Question 1, Option A',
                surface : '100'
              },
              {
                place : 'Question 2, Option B',
                surface : '200'
              }
          ]
        },
        {
            name : 'name2',
          infosName : [
                {
                place : 'Question 2, Option A',
                surface : '300'
              },
              {
                place : 'Question 2, Option B',
                surface : '400'
              }
          ]
        }
    ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
  setAnswer(iQuestion,iAnswer){
        this.$set(this.myAnswer,iQuestion,iAnswer)  
  },
  
    getAnswer(iQuestion,iAnswer){
        return {
        'name' : this.infos[iQuestion].infosName[iAnswer].place,
        'surface' : this.infos[iQuestion].infosName[iAnswer].surface
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you for u great answer, i will mark the answer as the correct one, i adapte ur code o my own and it work as expected thanks,
i have 2 question please,
1 - what does this.$refs did ?
2 - for example in the infos[] array we have 3 objects, the 2 first objects are the same as the code mention above, the thrid one have his infosName[] array empty its gonna throw an error

thank you again

Comment: You are welcome!   8-)

I have added answers to your two questions. (I think you mean this.$set, not this.$refs)

Comment: Hello @Eureka, i just wanna say that if we have for exemple 3 objects in the infos[] arrays and everything is not null it will throw an error, i've wonder that myAnswer : [0,0] is the cause of the prblm
im i right ?
thank u

Comment: I think you mean "everything *is* null", not "everything is *not* null". It is not setting myAnswer to [0,0] that causes the error. It is attempting to read the [0] element of an empty array. I have updated to avoid that. It is good practice that, if an array might have not enough elements, to check before you read from a particular element